# What email clients support cid: and mid: URIs?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, uri

[An answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223061/is-there-a-uri-schema-for-addressing-individual-email-messages/#20245850) tells me that there is [a [draft] standard URI schema](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2392) for referring to parts of an email message by their Content-ID and entire email messages by their Message-ID. [Another stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312687/how-to-embed-images-in-email/#4312865) shows how a cid: URL might be used in an HTML email to reference an attached image.

What clients support cid: URIs for referencing attached images in an html email? (I expect most)

What clients support mid: URIs for referencing images in another email in an html email? (I expect few to none)

What clients support mid: URIs for referencing whole other emails, either within new emails or from outside sources? (I expect few)

Of these, is this support optional or non-default in any of them?

Answer (score 2):

*(Not a full answer, but maybe helpful)*

For the *`mid` + Thunderbird* part of your question (however, please note that I didn’t test these add-ons yet, so I’m not sure if they really use `mid` URIs or some proprietary protocol):

The description of the Thunderbird add-on [ThunderLink](https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/thunderlink/) says (bold by me):

> ThunderLink lets you **link to email messages** in Thunderbird.
>   […]
>   ThunderLinks are based on the unique **message ID** generated when an email is sent.

The companion Firefox add-on [ThunderLinkSpotter](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/thunderlinkspotter/)

> […] enables the browser to recognize ThunderLinks and turn them into hyperlinks.

---

Another Thunderbird add-on is [MessageID-Finder](https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/messageid-finder/), which allows to open mails by right-clicking on a message-id (see a [screenshot on the website](http://messageidfinder.mozdev.org/)). But this would only work from within Thunderbird.

Answer (score 2):

## Thunderbird

Prior to version 78, [Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/) had support for mid: URLs via the [Thunderlink addon](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/thunderlink/), [version 1.2.11 and later](https://github.com/mikehardy/thunderlink/commit/02422f0a60911a37aa068b6f2a946e65288c8967).
However, with the [transition away from Legacy WebExtensions](https://developer.thunderbird.net/add-ons/updating/tb78) in Thunderbird 78 and later,
[Thunderlink ceased to function](https://github.com/mikehardy/thunderlink/issues/64).
Fortunately, Thunderbird [added native mid: URL scheme support in version 91](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/91.0/releasenotes/),
completing a [feature request dating from 2004](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=264270).
This works both for opening external mid: links via command line, e.g.:

```
thunderbird mid:123456.789012@example.com
```

as well as opening [internal mid: links in emails inside Thunderbird](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1735049).

## Evolution

[GNOME Evolution](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evolution/) has supported mid: URLs since version 3.39.1 and later,
completing a [feature request from 2017](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=788192).

## Apple Mail (sort of)

Apple Mail added [`message:` URLs in 2007](https://daringfireball.net/2007/12/message_urls_leopard_mail),
which [appears to work in a similar manner](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/196844/how-to-capture-mail-app-message-url-that-will-remain-persistent-when-message-is)
just with a non-standard URL scheme.
(Thunderlink [also had support for this non-standard scheme](https://github.com/mikehardy/thunderlink/commit/02422f0a60911a37aa068b6f2a946e65288c8967).)

## cid: URLs

Thunderbird [did not add cid: URL scheme support](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=264270#c12).
Neither did Evolution.
As far as I know, no email client supports the cid: scheme
as its usefulness seems to be not as compelling for most users,
although it could be used to e.g. link to message attachments.

Related:

- [Using the thunderbird command-line, how can I open a specific email by message-id?](https://superuser.com/questions/701887/using-the-thunderbird-command-line-how-can-i-open-a-specific-email-by-message-i)