# Using the thunderbird command-line, how can I open a specific email by message-id?

Tags: command-line, email, thunderbird

Thunderbird 24.2.0 has a `-mail` command-line parameter, with which a specific mail can be opened from the command line:

```
$ thunderbird --help
-mail <URL>        Open the message specified by this URL.
```

I know that one can use this function to open a specific email by an `imap://` URI, but I would like to be able to open a specific mail by its unique Message-ID, no matter which folder contains it. Is this possible, and if so, what does the URI look like?

The thunderlink add-on ( https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/thunderlink/ ) can create message-id based links to emails and then open these with the `-thunderlink` parameter, but I would still like to know if this can be done with just the `-mail` parameter.

Comment: I found this [page about a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=386919) but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Thunderbird bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1704421

Answer (score 6):

... for anyone still searching for a solution...
The following command worked for me (thunderbird 102.6.1):

`thunderbird mid:<the message ID>`

To make this nice and easy:

1. make sure the "thunderbird" command is in PATH (e.g. you can execute it in a terminal)
2. install [copy message ID](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/copy-message-id/) AddOn
3. in the preferences add the following **prefix**:  `thunderbird mid:`
   (make sure that there are no spaces before and after!)
4. open an email and click the `Copy Message ID` button
5. run the copied command in a terminal to open the mail

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2021-03-18:** The bug mentioned below has been fixed with [Thunderbird version 78.8.1](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/78.8.1/releasenotes/). No adjustments are necessary to open mails from the command line using *thunderbird.exe -mail <URL>*.

---

Opening messages with the `-mail` command line parameter is still possible with a current Thunderbird version (tested on **Windows 10** with version **78.6.0, 32-bit**).

However, this requires a small change of the module `MailNewsCommandLineHandler.jsm`, because otherwise a [getter-only error](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Fehler/Getter_only) occurs when calling the -mail command. The error can be traced via the Thunderbird error console (see below).

<strike>**Adjusting the module:**</strike>

1. Copy the file `c:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\omni.ja` into a temporary directory, rename the file to `omni.zip` and unpack it.
2. Open MailNewsCommandLineHandler.jsm, insert

   ```
   set _messenger(value) {
       return value;
   },
   ```

   after **line 22** and save the file.
3. [Repack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/About_omni.ja_(formerly_omni.jar)#Inspecting_and_repacking_omni.ja) all files using the following parameters: `zip.exe -0DXqr omni.ja *`. Rename the original file to `omni.ja.bak` and copy the repacked file to `c:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird`.
4. Messages can then be opened using the following command lines:

   ```
   thunderbird.exe -mail "mailbox-message://<folderLocation>#<messageKey>" (for local folders)
   thunderbird.exe -mail "imap-message://<folderLocation>#<messageKey>" (for IMAP folders)
   ```

**Finding the right URL:**

- *[Error console](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments_-_Thunderbird):* Open TB, select a message and open the error console (Ctrl + Shift + J). Enter the line

  ```
  var hdr = gFolderDisplay.selectedMessage; alert(hdr.folder.getUriForMsg(hdr));
  ```

  and press enter. This will open a window with the URL for the selected message.
- *SQLite database:* If you plan to build your own search tool (e.g. by writing a Python plugin for the [Wox desktop launcher](https://github.com/Wox-launcher/Wox)), it is perhaps best to create the URLs dynamically.

  The Thunderbird database can be found under `%APPDATA%\Thunderbird\Profiles\<profile>\global-messages-db.sqlite`. The tables **messagesText_content**, **messages** and **folderLocations** contain all information needed to assemble the URL strings.

  A simple Python script that can be used to generate the URLs might look something like this:

  ```python
  import sqlite3
  import re
  import sys
  import os
  import json

  # Replace db_path with your profile location
  # (Help > Troubleshooting Information > Open Folder)
  db_path = r"%APPDATA%\Thunderbird\Profiles\xxxxxxxx.default"

  con = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(db_path, "global-messages-db.sqlite"))
  cursor = con.cursor()

  query = """
      SELECT messagesText_content.*, 
             strftime('%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M', 
                      DATETIME(messages.date/1000000, 
                      "unixepoch", "localtime")),
             messages.folderID,
             messages.messageKey
      FROM messagesText_content
      JOIN messages ON messages.id=messagesText_content.docid
      WHERE messagesText_content.c3author NOT LIKE "%daemon%"
      OR messagesText_content.c3author NOT LIKE "%DAEMON%"
      ORDER BY messages.date DESC
      """

  def get_messages():
      messages = []
      cursor.execute(query)
      for i in cursor:
          messages.append({
              "text": i[1] if i[1] else "",
              "subject": i[2], 
              "attachments": f'attach:{i[3]}' if i[3] else "",
              "sender": i[4], 
              "receiver": i[5], 
              "date": i[6], 
              "folder_id": i[7],
              "message_key": i[8]
              })
      return messages

  def get_folders():
      cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM folderLocations")
      return {i[0]: i[1:] for i in cursor.fetchall()}

  def collect_urls(terms):
      r1 = "(mailbox|imap)(?=://)"
      r2 = "\\1-message"
      messages = get_messages()
      folders = get_folders()
      results = {}
      for msg in messages:
          msg_str = str(msg.values()).lower()
          if all(i.lower() in msg_str for i in terms):
              folder = folders.get(msg["folder_id"])[0]
              url = re.sub(r1, r2, folder)
              url = f'{url}#{msg["message_key"]}'
              msg["text"] = msg["text"][:50]
              results.update({url: msg})
      return json.dumps(
          results, 
          indent=4,
          ensure_ascii=False
          )

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      if len(sys.argv) > 1:
          print(collect_urls(sys.argv[1:]))
  ```

  Just use it like so:

  ```
   <C:\>python collect_urls.py search terms test message

   {
       "imap-message://a%40b.cd@imap.provider.com/INBOX#28649": {
           "text": "Test message contains search terms",
           "subject": "Test message",
           "attachments": "",
           "sender": "John Doe <e@f.gh>",
           "receiver": "i@j.kl",
           "date": "2022-10-02, 14:20",
           "folder_id": 607,
           "message_key": 28649
       }
   }
  ```

Comment: Do you know how stable this number is? Like if I have two thunderbird instances downloading synced with the same email accounts would they share the same id?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell, IMAP accounts seem to share the IDs across different Thunderbird installations and profiles, e.g. _imap-message://a%40b.cd@imap.provider.com/INBOX#28579_ would always lead to the same message, regardless of where you retrieve it.

Comment: Great, thanks! But if I move the message to another folder than INBOX I guess it will get a different number/adress.

Comment: The IMAP URLs are stabIe even when messages are moved to different folder locations, I think. I've just added a small Python script so that you can check the URLs for your specific use case.